# The cacls command doesn't give access denied error when denying permission to a user for a folder but for granting permission it does.Why?

Tags: windows, cmd

The following code gives no error:

`cacls d:\images /e /c /d %username%`

But this code gives an access denied error:

`cacls d:\images /e /c /g %username%:f`

I have to grant permission by the security tab in properties of that folder to let the above command work without an error.How to resolve this?

[Please consider this image for the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Vbj.png)

Comment: The first command denies all access to the user, which includes the right to modify the DACL. The owner is almost always granted this right impicitly (barring an OWNER_RIGHTS entry that dictates otherwise), so apparently the user doesn't own the directory. If it's owned by the Administrators group, and the user is a UAC-restricted administrator, then the user can modify the DACL from an elevated command prompt. If it's not owned by the Administrators group, then first take ownership by running `takeown /f d:\images` from an elevated prompt, which works by enabling SeTakeownershipPrivilege.

Comment: So I'll have to take ownership of a folder every time I want to implement this.Is there a way to take ownership of everything?

Comment: I cannot take ownership once the permission is denied with cacls command.What about that?

Comment: You can take ownership from an elevated (i.e. run as administrator) command prompt using `takeown /f d:\images`.